# Custom shared library cannot be found even when search path defined

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have the following files:

```
.
├── combinatorics
│   ├── permutation.cpp
│   └── permutation.h
├── main.cpp
└── math
    ├── basic.cpp
    └── basic.h
```

and am trying to create a shared library by doing these steps:

```
g++ -c -Wall -std=c++14 -fpic combinatorics/permutation.cpp -o permutations.o
g++ -c -Wall -std=c++14 -fpic math/basic.cpp -o mathbasic.o
g++ -shared -o combmath.so permutations.o mathbasic.o
g++ -Wall -std=c++14 main.cpp  -L. -o output -lcombmath
```

but I am getting the following message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcombmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am specifiying to search from current directory with -L. so that is why I am asking why it's still not finding it, I don't know why the downvote

Comment: `-lpermutations` is not shown in your list of commands. It only surfaces in the error message.

Comment: I pasted the wrong command, thank you. Could you please remove the down vote?

Comment: I don't know why this got a down vote, it's a common mistake when naming custom libraries that do not start with lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linkage option `-lfoo` directs the linker to search for a file
`libfoo.so` (shared library) or `libfoo.a` (static library) in the specified
linker search directories (`-L/x/y/z`) and then in the linker's default
search directories, stopping when it finds either one of those files and
preferring `libfoo.so` if it finds both in the same directory.

For your linkage:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++14 main.cpp  -L. -o output -lcombmath
```

to succeed, therefore, you need previously to have built `libcombmath.so`
in the same directory with the command:

```
g++ -shared -o libcombmath.so permutations.o mathbasic.o
```

and not built `combmath.so`, as you have done with the command:

```
g++ -shared -o combmath.so permutations.o mathbasic.o
```

Comment: so I have to add the lib prefix